# Hex string compression program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Create a program to compress 'mac number' in Python.
I am trying here to shrink consecutive zeros with under the rules of that.
But I encountered some problem with the last index of the 'string' as last field
If Last field has '0000' ; It Couldn't get the Answer Which I Supposed.
It give the Answer the last field two times with double colon(::) in between.
Please help me to solve this Problem

This is my coding part:

```
hex_num = 'fe80:0d5e:0d2f:f180:f542:0d5e:00f0:f45d:3d5e:0000'

first_list = []
second_list = []

dec_value = ([(int(i,16)) for i in hex_num.split(":")])
print('list :',dec_value)

for i in range(len(dec_value) - 1):
    if dec_value[i] == 0:
        if dec_value[i] + dec_value[i + 1] == 0:
            ## print(dec_value[i], dec_value[i + 1])
            pass

        if dec_value[i + 1] != 0:
            p = dec_value.index(dec_value[i + 1])
            break        
    else:        
        ## print(dec_value[i], dec_value[i + 1])
        p = dec_value.index(dec_value[i])
        first_list.append(dec_value[i])

for h in range(p, len(dec_value) - 1):
    second_list.append(dec_value[h])

non_leading_zeros1 = ":".join([str(hex(h).replace("0x",'')) for h in first_list])
non_leading_zeros2 = ":".join([str(hex(h).replace("0x",'')) for h in second_list])

print(non_leading_zeros1 +'::'+ non_leading_zeros2)
```

OutPut :fe80:d5e:d2f:f180:f542:d5e:f0:f45d:3d5e::3d5e

it is wrong according to the rules of mac number or ipv6 number compression

expected value:fe80:d5e:d2f:f180:f542:d5e:f0:f45d:3d5e::

Comment: Hi Pramu, could you post what your sample input, and expected vs unexpected output is?  It will greatly expedite solving your problem.

Comment: this is wrong output:fe80:d5e:d2f:f180:f542:d5e:f0:f45d:3d5e::3d5e

Comment: but i need like this :fe80:d5e:d2f:f180:f542:d5e:f0:f45d:3d5e::

Comment: It would be helpful to give some sample input and expected outputs, and what you got now.

Comment: stackoverflow is a place for Q&A that's geared towards helping future visitors, so it would be great if you could edit your question and place the expected values in there instead of the comments.

Comment: this answer incorrect:fe80:d5e:d2f:f180:f542:d5e:f0:f45d:3d5e::3d5e  ; becouse it is not compression properly

Comment: I interpret your problem statement as saying you have an issue when last digits are `0000` yet I do not see `0000` in your sample value.  Does `0000` matter or not?

Comment: not zero , i need to compress this string. please think this is a mac address